# I have a Unity game and I want my player to move relative to the camera

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Here's my code. Currently, the player moves forwards relative to a fix plane. Rotating the player/camera has no affect on which direction they travel when I press the "go forward" key.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MainController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;
    float jumpSpeed = 0.5f;
    bool isGrounded;
    private Rigidbody rb;
    public GameObject player;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        Vector3 movement = new Vector3(moveHorizontal, 0.0f, moveVertical);

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") || Input.GetAxis("Right Trigger") > 0f && isGrounded)
        {
            rb.AddForce(Vector3.up * jumpSpeed, ForceMode.Impulse);
            isGrounded = false;
        }

        if (isGrounded)
        {
            rb.AddForce(movement * speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        else
        {
            rb.AddForce((movement/4) * speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }

    void OnCollisionStay()
    {
        isGrounded = true;
    }
    void OnCollisionExit()
    {
        isGrounded = false;
    }
}
```

How do I make it so that the player moves relative to the camera's direction?

Answer (score 0):

It's because `RigidBody.AddForce()` adds force in *absolute* direction, no matter which direction the gameobject is looking.

You should try using [RigidBody.AddRelativeForce()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddRelativeForce.html), like:

```
if (isGrounded)
{
    rb.AddRelativeForce(movement * speed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a better way to do this, but see if it results in the expected behavior:

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
    float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

    Vector3 looking = (transform.rotation * Vector3.forward).normalized;

    Vector3 perpendicular = Vector2.Perpendicular(new Vector2(looking.x, looking.z));
    perpendicular.z = perpendicular.y;
    perpendicular.y = looking.y;

    Vector3 vertical = moveVertical * looking;
    Vector3 horizontal = moveHorizontal * perpendicular;

    Vector3 movement = vertical - horizontal;

    ...
}
```